# setImageResource() Returns null

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get images from my asset folder and setting them to my variable called insectImage. Here is what I've done:

```
InsectRecyclerAdapter.InsectHolder insectHolder = holder;
Insect insectItem = (Insect) recyclerViewItems.get(position);

String imageName = insectItem.getImageName();
Log.d("imageName",imageName);
int imageResID = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
Log.d("imageID", ""+imageResID);
insectHolder.insectImage.setImageResource(imageResID);
```

`imageResID` returns 0 in the logcat, but the `imageName` variable is set to one of my images that exist in my assets folder. Logcat is saying that setImageResource(imageResID) is returning null.

How can I set the `imageResID` to the `imageName` that's in my asset folder?

Comment: *"Logcat is saying that setImageResource(imageResID) is returning null."* - Not it isn't.  `setImageResource` is a `void` method.  It cannot possibly return anything ... let alone `null`.  If you are going to "summarize" error messages for us, you need to do it accurately.  A better idea is to copy and paste the error message and stacktrace from logcat **without** attempting to summarize it.

Answer (score 0):

If `imageResId` is zero, that means that `getIdentifier` cannot find a resource with the name information that you gave.

Reference:

- [`int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

That's the root cause of the problem.  What happens after that is just "consequences" of the earlier error.

Solution: find out why the resource identifier lookup fails.

- Have you got the `name` wrong?
- The `defType`?
- The `defPackage`?
- Is the image resource there?
- Is it in the right place?